# grails assets defaulting to web-app/js and css folder

Tags: grails, assets

I presume there is a way, just not done much research on it... just wondering (this is in the case of a plugin) although I doubt it would make any difference.

How would one go about declaring assets to refer to web-app/css and web-app/js folders

Assuming this is the defaults:

```
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
    <asset:stylesheet href="application.css" />
```

How would one go about lets say defining :

```
<asset:stylesheet src="myplugin.css"/>
```

where myplugin.css is uploaded to web-app/css

This then being compatible with both resources/assets....

The purpose of this question is to stop duplicate css files in multiple locations...

Comment: I may not have understood the question appropriately but if you are looking to know if asset pipeline plugin will be able to look for the static resources under `web-app/css` in a plugin, then yes it can. asset pipeline searches for resources in `assets/*` path and then falls over to `web-app/*` path to identify a resource. If you have static resources in `web-app` then those resources are already in asset-pipeline's radar. I hope that helps.

Comment: wicked thanks I think it does I will test it now